zero gatos ou zero gato?
Nesta página: Uso do plural ou singular em zeros/decimais está escrito:

'A prática em Portugal é a de se dizer «zero dias», tal como se diz
«zero graus», «zero horas» (ver «zero valores» no Dicionário da
Academia das Ciências de Lisboa). Contudo, a edição brasileira do
Dicionário Houaiss atesta o singular, em usos como «zero grau» e «zero
hora». Há, pois, indícios de que há variação entre o português europeu
e o português brasileiro quanto ao uso de zero a modificar nomes. Em
suma, parece que em Portugal há preferência por «zero dias», enquanto
no Brasil é melhor «zero dia».
Nota: O consultor Luciano Eduardo Oliveira confirma que na edição em
linha da Folha de S. Paulo, as ocorrências de zero com substantivo no
singular prevalecem sobre as que incluem o substantivo modificado no
plural (informação recebida em 4/02/2012).'
in Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa,
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-zero-com-nomes/17100
[consultado em 13-10-2024]

eu tenho o dicionário eletrônico Houaiss e não encontrei a recomendação mencionadano texto do uso, no Brasil  do singular para o zero(zero gato e não zero gatos). Alguémpoderia confirmar?
existe uma discussão parcial aqui: Uso do plural ou singular em zeros/decimais

Receio que essa pergunta seja uma duplicada da Números e plural. Quanto ao Houaiss, ele dá exemplos: "numeral 3 num.card. (adj.2g.2n.) diz-se do elemento inicial de uma série ‹fez z. grau hoje de madrugada› ‹esta rádio sai do ar à z. hora›.

Nova resposta.

No Dicionário de Dificuldades da Língua Protuguesa, Domingos Paschoal Cegalla também diz que a concordância deve ser no singular. Logo, a forma correta seria "zero gato".
